# Transition one image to another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I use following code:

```
  <div style="" id="mainimg"></div>
```

And then:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#mainimg').animate({
        opacity: "0"
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/corrals/maocorral.png)').animate({
            opacity: "1"
        });
    });
});
```

It makes image disappear to "0" and then appear to "1" smoothly. Is there a way to achieve fading between images without completly disappearing first image?

I've found a way to do this by: (with custom css)

```
<img id="first" src="images/2.png">
<img id="second" src="images/1.png">
```

Script:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#first').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#second').fadeOut(1000);
},
function() {
    $('#first').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#second').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

But I'm not satisfied about having for example 500  tags one on another on the page. I want to load them if user request to show it, like in the first example. Do you know maybe some extra libraries?

Edit:
I want to make this: https://jsfiddle.net/0fw8zz2g/ without writing one  on another (imagine 500 images for example)

Comment: create a fiddle link

Comment: So, what you want is to get rid of the ids?

Answer (score 0):

Your are in the right path. A transition like this can be done by just having two images, one "behind" the other (using css `absolute` position). Then, if you want to reuse this code, instead of using IDs, you use jQuery selectors and show your first image at the time you hide your second (next) one.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fw8zz2g/2/)